# Does KERS in F1 cars cause sparks?

Tags: formula-1

I'm watching the Abu Dhabi GP and I keep seeing sparks coming out from behind the cars. Maybe it's more clear because it's in the evening and it's dark, but the commentator doesn't say anything indicating a problem with the car, and it doesn't happen all of the time so I can only assume it's something that is supposed to happen and is maybe related to KERS.

If so, what is it that causes the sparks? And if it's not KERS, what is causing the sparks?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/sport/formula1/32375705), the sparks are caused by titanium skid plates on the underside of the car contacting the track.

Comment: Also, its related more to the track also. Singopore GP at Marina Bay has sparks flying literally every lap

Answer (score 4):

**KERS Does Not Cause Sparks**

KERS stands for kinetic energy recovery.  It is a set of magnets driven by the crank of the engine that become 'excited' by electrical impulse on deceleration of the vehicle.  The magnets then create an electromagnet field that creates resistance to the wheels and slows the car down while recovery electrical energy that is then stored chemically in batteries.

Upon acceleration the KERS unit can have it's polarity changed and turned into an electric motor that will drive the car forward in conjunction with the ICE (Internal Combustion Engine) and add power via electrical energy.

**Sparks**

As @davidmneedham indicates in [this post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/does-kers-in-f1-cars-cause-sparks/12528#12528https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/does-kers-in-f1-cars-cause-sparks/12528#12528) the sparks are from titanium skid plates mounted underneath the cars.

These skid plates are defined in the 2016 Technical Regulations Section 3 Subpart 13.

To give you an idea of how tightly defined the technical regulations are I'm pasting the entire regulation related to skid plates.

> 3.13 Plank and skids   :
>   3.13.1 Beneath  the surface formed  by  all parts   lying   on  the reference   plane,  a   rectangular plank,  with
>   a   50mm    radius  (+/-2mm)    on  each    front   corner, must    be  fitted. This    plank   may comprise    no
>   more    than    three   pieces, the forward one of  which   may not be  any less    than    1000mm  in  length, 
>   but must:
>   a) Extend   longitudinally  from    a   point   lying   330mm   behind  the front   wheel   centre  line    to
>   the rear    wheel   centre  line.
>   b) Be   made    from    an  homogeneous material    with    a   specific    gravity between 1.3 and 1.45.
>   c) Have a   width   of  300mm   with    a   tolerance   of  +/- 2mm.
>   d) Have a   thickness   of  10mm    with    a   tolerance   of  +/- 1mm.
>   e) Have a   uniform thickness   when    new.
>   f) Have no holes    or  cut outs    other   than    those   necessary   to  fit the skids   permitted   by  3.13.2
>   or  the fasteners   permitted   by  3.13.3, or  those   holes   specifically    mentioned   in  g)  below.
>   g) Have seven   precisely   placed  holes   the positions   of  which   are detailed    in  Drawing 1.  In
>   order   to  establish   the conformity  of  the plank   after   use,    its thickness   will    only    be
>   measured    in  the four    50mm    diameter    holes   and the two forward 80mm    diameter    holes.
>   Four    further 10mm    diameter    holes   are permitted   provided    their   sole    purpose is  to allow
>   access  to  the bolts   which   secure  the Accident    Data    Recorder    to  the survival    cell.
>   h) Be   fixed   symmetrically   about   the car centre  line    in  such    a   way that    no  air may pass
>   between it  and the surface formed  by  the parts   lying   on  the reference   plane.
>   The lower   edge    of  the periphery   of  the plank   may be  chamfered   at  an  angle   of  30° to  a   depth
>   of  8mm;    the trailing    edge    however may be  chamfered   over    a   distance    of  200mm   to  a   depth   of
>   8mm.
>   3.13.2 The  lower   surface of  the plank   may be  fitted  with    flush   mounted metal   skids   which   :
>   a) Have a   total   area    no  greater than    20000mm²    when    viewed  from    directly    beneath the 
>   car.
>   2016 F1 Technical   Regulations 17/90 2 December 2015
>   ©   2015 Fédération Internationale  de  l’Automobile
>   b) Are  no  greater than    4000mm² in  area    individually    when    viewed  from    directly    beneath 
>   the car.
>   c) Are  fitted  in  order   that    their   entire  lower   surfaces    are visible from    directly    beneath the 
>   car.
>   d) Must have    a   minimum cross   sectional   thickness   of  15mm    across  its external    boundaries
>   in  plan    view.   The minimum wall    thickness   between an  internal    fixing  hole    and the 
>   external    boundaries  of  the skid    must    be  no  less    than    7.5mm.
>   e) Must have    an  upper   surface no  more    than    3mm below   the reference   plane.
>   f) Must be  designed    such    that        they    are secured to  the car using   the fasteners   described   in
>   3.13.3  and that,   when    viewed  from    directly    beneath the car,    no  part    of  the skid    is  more
>   than    50mm    from    the centreline  of  a   fastener    which   passes  through that    skid.
>   g) Must be  made    from    Titanium    alloy.
>   3.13.3 The  plank   and skids   must    be  fixed   to  the car using   fasteners   which   :
>   a) Are  no  smaller than    M6  and are made    from    grade   12.9    steel.
>   b) If   used    to  attach  a   skid    to  the car,    must    employ  at  least   1   fastener    per 1000mm2 of  skid
>   area.
>   c) If   used    to  attach  a   skid    to  the car,    the team    must    be  able    to  show    by  calculation that    the 
>   shanks  of  the fasteners   (which  may be  no less than    6mm diameter)   are the weakest 
>   point   in  the attachment  of  the skids   to  the car.
>   d) May  use a   load    spreading   washer  if  required.
>   The total   area    of  the fasteners   and any load    spreading   washers employed    with    them    when
>   viewed  from    directly    beneath the car must    be  less    than    5000mm2
>   .   The area    of  any single
>   fastener    plus    its load    spreading   washer  may not exceed  500mm2
>   .
>   No  part    of  any fastener    or  load    spreading   washer  may be  more    than    8mm below   the reference
>   plane.  For the avoidance   of  doubt,  the skids referred  to  in  3.13.2  will    not be  treated as  load
>   spreading   washers.